# want to create a method setRate to adjust the flat rate of discount and that affects all retail customers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Want to change the rod=0.1 value using setRateso that it will get changed in whole class

```
class RetailCustomer:

    def __init__(self, price, rod=0.1):
        self.price = price
        self.rod = rod

        def getRate(self):
        return self.rod

    def setRate(self, rate):
        self.rod = rate
        print("After changing Rate: ", self.rod)
        return self.rod

RetailCustomer(int(input('Discount Rate: '))).setRate(10)
```

#And also tried to use this "RetailCustomer.setRate(10)" but it throws"TypeError: setRate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rate' " this error, as "(int(input('Discount Rate: ')))" this line is not needed I think

Comment: Why is `setRate` static? static methods don't have a `self`. In your calls `self` is the integer `20`

Comment: okay self is not needed in static, after removing self how should I call that self.rod from __init__ then. And if I don't use static method how can I create a setRate method that can affect all the customers after adjusting the flat rate

Comment: A static method like a function outside your class. So you need to write with that in your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods can't access the instance `self`. Don't use `@staticmethod` for setter methods, use it (with moderation) for utility functions that do not need to access the properties of your class. If you want to have methods that get or set a property, you don't need to call `__init__`, which is the constructor of your object. Instead you can just return the value or set the value as following:

```
# Methods in your class
def getRate(self):
    return self.rod
def setRate(self, rate):
    self.rod = rate

# Outside the class
obj = Myobject(price=5)
obj.setRate(10)


>>> obj.getRate()
>>> 10
```